# React Router link to non React page in application

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I have a web application written in asp.net. I have been writing a react application to sit on a page in this application using web methods to send data back and forwards. It is working great and I am just doing the last couple of bits.

The routing is set out so that any page with a react app on it will use the url and route in the appropriate component.

I want to have links in these react components that link off to other non react pages in the application.

The problem is that this application might sit in a virtual directory in IIS, so the react app needs to know the app domain virtual path. I have cheated a little bit and got the asp.net app to write out the current app domain virtual path to a hidden field, which is then picked it up with javascript and fed  into the basename of the browser router. This seemed to work really well, it generated the links with the virtual directory, so the "to" property of the link was turned from **/NonReactPage.aspx** into **https://domain/ThisSite/NonReactPage.aspx**. All is good, when I right click or middle mouse and open the link in a new tab it goes to the right page.

The problem is that when it click it normally staying on the same tab, the react app tries to route it like its another component, finds no routing for that URL and shows nothing on the screen.

I need it to:

- Jump out of the react app and off to the other page as if it is a regular link
- Use the virtual path i supplied so this asp.net application can sit at any level on a webserver
- I would like to set this Virtual path in a single high level place so I dont have to pass it to every component I route to.

*N.B. Im sorry, i could not get this snippet to run properly in the code snippet thing, i get this message like "Script error." I cant figure out how to fix it. (Im quite new to react as you might have guessed!). Hopefully there is enough information here that you might be able to answer*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route } from 'react-router';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('MyReactApp');
const sitePath = document.getElementById('SitePath');

export class MyAquinasReactApp extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route path='/APageThatUsesReact.aspx' component={SomeComponent} />
                <Route path='/ASubFolder/AnotherPageThatUsesReact.aspx' component={AnotherComponent} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

if (rootElement) {
    ReactDOM.render(

        <BrowserRouter basename={sitePath.value}>
            <MyAquinasReactApp />
        </BrowserRouter>,
        rootElement);
}

export class SomeComponent extends Component {

  render() {
  return 
    <div>
      <div>This is the content of the component</div>
      <Link to="/NonReactPage.aspx"> this is a link to a non react page in the application</Link
    </div>
  }

export class AnotherComponent extends Component {

  render() {
  return 
    <div>
      <div>This is another componenet, it doesn't have any links and is only here to illustrate the routing setup</div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="SitePath" value="/ThisApp/" />

<div class="MyReactApp"></div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by 'to sit on a page in this application using web methods' please?

Comment: How familiar are you with asp.net? Imagine a master page with the main menu across the top, another menu down the left hand side and a content pane taking up the rest of the space.

In our old development process all of our asp.net is coded into the content pane and the application fires a postback whenever you want to handle dynamic content.

We are looking into slowly replacing all the asp.net dynamic content with react apps and API calls. The only thing in the content pane now is <div class="MyReactApp"></div> and the BrowserRouter loads a component if the path matches the URL.

Comment: @EvalKeneval why dont you use an anchor tag as mentioned below. and then add a url rewrite rule in your IIS to manipulate the url into looking like whatever you want. you can add it to your web.config file (assuming you are uisng web forms as you talked about postback)

Comment: you would need to install https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite to perform url re-writing on IIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an `anchor tag`.
The Link from react-router is for Single-Page Application, underneath the hood if prevents the page from refreshing itself.

```
<a href="/APageThatUsesReact.aspx' />
```

A universal anchor will also do.

```
function UniversalAnchor({ path }) {
  return <a href=`domain/thisGlobal/${path}` />
}
```

Comment: Hi Prateek, Im looking for the ability to link away to other pages, but also have the site folder added to the start of any link the same way that browserrouter might.

Comment: The browser router only helps in the context of `SPA` and under the current hostname on which it's running and the component has to defined in React. 
I recommend using `anchor` tags to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I get the thing about it being only for SPAs, however, I am trying to figure out a way to put the site and the domain in. take the link https://domain/ThisSite/NonReactPage.aspx for example, I need a way to set "ThisSite" globally and any anchor tags automatically build it onto any link.

Comment: Why not create an `UniversalAnchor` component that does that and uses prop to attach itself to `ThisSite` and you could use that component all through your project.

Comment: Thanks Prateek, I will have a play around with this and see how it fits in. I was kinda hoping there would be some kind of component that did all the URL building like the BrowserRouter does. If I coded it myself I might miss some subtleties of URL generation.

Comment: @EvalKeneval  You could use `createBrowserHistory` to create a `history` object and listen to those changes and handle your routes differently. Since everything route changes pass through that object, you have to be extra careful how to handle all routes. I would not recommend that though, since it may brew complexity, rather just a simple component like a `UniversalAnchor`